# What is the Python equivalent of qexp in R?

Tags: python, r

So, I thought the python equivalent for qexp in R would be in scipy.stats.expon.

For example in R I want to get the upper 9999th quantile:

qexp(0.9999, rate = 10) would give me 0.921034.

In python:
stats.expon.interval(0.9999, scale = 10) would give an array of [0.0005000125004166272, 99.03487552536237] and you would just get the second element in the array for the upper 9999th.

But those two answers are completely different. Am I doing something incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stats.expon.interval()` returns the inner interval that covers `alpha` percent of the probability density function.

What you're looking for is `stats.expon.ppf()`, the percent point function, or as scipy kindly tells us, the percentiles.

Doing `stats.expon.ppf(0.9999, scale=10)` gives us the desired `0.921034`.

[Check out their documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html)